# Errors information logged by the kernel, troubleshoot a custom-built kernel by /var/log/kern.log

Tags: usb, kernel, syslog, gvfs

I'm trying to  troubleshoot a custom-built kernel by /var/log/kern.log command.  In this on the logs its showing errors related to gvfsd-metadata.
Is this errors cause any problems to PC?
How to fix this errors?, I've attached the logs below

```
   root@yash20-desktop:/home/yash20# tail -f /var/log/syslog
    Sep  5 10:27:19 yash20-desktop kernel: [   36.512190] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
    Sep  5 10:27:38 yash20-desktop kernel: [   55.529151] audit_printk_skb: 42 callbacks suppressed
    Sep  5 10:27:38 yash20-desktop kernel: [   55.529154] type=1400 audit(1536123458.500:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2423 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Sep  5 10:27:38 yash20-desktop kernel: [   55.529161] type=1400 audit(1536123458.500:38): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2423 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Sep  5 10:28:50 yash20-desktop kernel: [  127.759992] gvfsd-metadata[4220]: segfault at 7ffb6405c000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007ffe99258ff0 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
    Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.035233] gvfsd-metadata[4244]: segfault at 7f4272d13000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007ffccb5eebf0 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
    Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.224081] gvfsd-metadata[4250]: segfault at 7f5a9ded4000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007fff06f5e270 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
    Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.367639] gvfsd-metadata[4275]: segfault at 7f21625eb000 ip 0000000000406885 sp
```

00007fffe68e08c0 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]
    Sep  5 10:28:51 yash20-desktop kernel: [  128.499979] gvfsd-metadata[4283]: segfault at 7facae55e000 ip 0000000000406885 sp 00007ffc36778990 error 4 in gvfsd-metadata[400000+11000]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gvfsd-metadata` is provided by package `gvfs` which is the GNOME Virtual Filesystem.

It should have nothing to do with your kernel, it appears on your logs because it segfaults
and a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=ik&channel=fs&ei=qYmPW42ENsbEwAKO_6DwCA&q=gvfsd-metadata%20segfault&oq=gvfsd-metadata%20segfault&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1l2.11348.11495.0.12175.2.2.0.0.0.0.135.240.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.105....0._0NiHuQoNK8) shows some (old) bugs.

You can check if the segfault is related to your custom kernel by (temporarily) installing a stock kernel and rebooting your system into it,
then check if the segfaults go away.